# Genaralize a json function to check the input value against min and max values

Tags: python, json

I do not have good coding background, and I need help generalizing this function - write one single function that accepts the input data (json blob) and compares it against the Min and Max values (range_file.json) in python.

```
Sample Input data
var = {'data': 46, 'b': 'AB_09200012', 'h_ID': '0111'} 

#Acceptable range of limit file:
'''
range_file.json:
[{"Parameters": "Air Temperature","b": "AB_09200013", "Min": -80,"Max": 60},
{"Parameters": "Soil Temperature","b": "AB_09200014", "Min": -50,"Max": 50},
{"Parameters": "Humidity","b": "AB_09200012","Min": 1,"Max": 100}]
'''

#Acceptable range of limit for Air Temperature
range_AirTemperature = '{"Parameters": "Air Temperature","b":"AB_09200013", "Min": -80,"Max": 60}'
range_AirT = json.loads(range_AirTemperature)

#Checking if the input data is with the acceptable range of limit

#Check Air Temperature
if  var["b"] == range_AirT['b']:
    if var['data'] < AirT['Min'] and var['data'] > AirT['Max']:
        print('Value out of range:', var['data'])
    else:
        print('Temp Values within range')
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Above are the codes that I have tried but I could not go past that to generalize it. That is where I need help. Thank you.

Comment: So, just to be clear, we're not going to write the code for you. Surely you must have some ideas about how to do this? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You've made it harder on yourself by not solving the initial problem of reading the data as a list of dictionaries in the first place. Try to avoid compounding problems on problems... solve one problem at a time.

Had you figured out how to read the data, or reconstructed the list from your separate dictionaries, you'd be in a much better spot to use a loop:

```
import json

with open('range_file.json') as stream:
    ranges = json.load(stream)

def check_within_range(var):
    for r in ranges:
        if r['ontology'] != var['ontology']:
            continue

        # Note the use of "or" here
        if var['data'] < r['Min'] or var['data'] > r['Max']:
            print('Value out of range:', var['data'])
        else:
            print('Value within range')

var = {'data': 0, 'ontology': 'AB_09200012', 'h_ID': '0111'}

check_within_range(var)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions, and the solution! Greatly appreciated!